# Logarithmic Y scale, multiple value plot

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, logarithm

I'd like to plot mutiple values onto the same graph with a logarithmic Y scale. The following code plots the values onto a linear scale graph and works, however trying to change 'plot' with 'semilogy' outputs a blank graph.

```
hold on;
for i = 1:10
  [val1(i), val2, val3, val4] = myFunct(i, fileName);
end;

plot(val1);
hold off;
```

What do I need to change to create a Y scale that is logarithmic?

Edited code:

```
hold on;
for i = 1:10
  [val1(i), val2, val3, val4] = myFunct(i, fileName);
end;

val1(1) = 0.000001; %index 1 is always zero, index 2 may or may not be zero
val1(2) = 0.000001;

semilogy(val1);
hold off;
```

Output of the above code:

[image: Output]

Comment: Try typing `help semilogy` on the command line ...

Comment: @BasSwinckels I've read the semilogy documentation. I should just be able to switch 'plot' with 'semilogy' like the documentation says, but it gives me a blank graph or the same graph as 'plot' but without a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Are some of the x or y values negative or zero?

Comment: @Naveh some are zero, now if I remember correctly logs and zero don't mix. Its been a while... how can I avoid this error?

Comment: @Naveh Even after manually adding a value to the zero values before calling semilogy, the output is still a linear Y scale graph! Even though I've changed plot to semilogy.

Comment: Are you sure of this? Could you edit the question to include your updated code?

Comment: @Naveh Code has been added.

Comment: This should give you what you want. I'm not sure why you are saying this gives a linear scale graph. Could you upload your graph as an image to the question? (You can save a figure with File -> Save As -> Choosing an image format such as png).

Comment: @Naveh Sure, its in the main question now. The graph was output using the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: This has to be some kind of figure problem, probably due to other code you are running. Remove the `hold` commands (you don't need them as you have a single plot), do `close all`, and try again.

Comment: @Naveh Finally it worked! It was the hold commands. Thank you Naveh :)

Comment: Good. I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hold on` command prevents the figure from being updated from the regular `plot` you did before to `semilogy`. To solve this you should close your figure and run the code again.

Note that there is no reason to use `hold` commands if you only have one plotting command. The purpose of `hold` is to enable several plotting commands to be overlayed in the same figure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
% Calculate
for i = 1:10
  [val1(i), val2, val3, val4] = myFunct(i, fileName);
end

% Plot
figure;
plot(val1+eps);
set(gca, 'YScale','log');
```